# shell $@ variable assignment and iteration

Tags: bash, shell, sh

```
function f() {
    for arg; do
        echo "$arg"
    done
}

f 'hello world' 'second arg' '3rdarg'
```

this works fine:

```
hello world
second arg
3rdarg
```

but when do I assign `$@` to some variable, and then it goes wrong:

```
function f() {
    local args="$@"
    for arg in "$args"; do
        echo "$arg"
    done
}
```

## output:

```
hello world second arg 3rdarg
```

when I unquote the `$args`, then each argument was split into single word:

```
hello
world
second
arg
3rdarg
```

Lastly, I wonder if there's a way to define variable like $@. Any response will be appreciated.

Comment: The *generic* way to assign a new value to `$@` is: `set -- "first argument" "second argument" "etc"`.

Comment: ...but yes, as you've discovered here, you can't represent an array of strings in a variable whose type is a scalar (thus, a _single_ string).

Comment: Since the `$@` is an array as you indicated, then how to manipulate it as an regular array variable, such as unset `${array[1]}`, `${array[1]} = 'hello'`, etc? Or it's just s special case, and the only way to manipulate is use the `shift`,`unshift` and `set`?

Additionally, the `'-p'` option of the 'declare' built-in could print the related type of the var, could it be used against the $@ var as well?

Comment: Yes, it's a special case (it's the only array available in POSIX sh, with which standard bash complies, which doesn't otherwise support arrays). No, `declare -p` and like tools don't work for `"$@"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to use an array:

```
function f() {
    local args=("$@")             # values in parentheses
    for arg in "${args[@]}"; do   # array expansion syntax
        echo "$arg"
    done
}
```